# i am getting infinite results when i use fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have this function in a class named ManageNews:

```
function getLatestNews($limit){

    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit");
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    if ($count !== 0){

          while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

              return $row;

          }

    }

}
```

When i try to get the info the news posts from the database i get them as an array, i tried doing `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` but it puts them in multidimensional arrays so i can't get them all using `$row[0]['column name'];` because they aren't all [0] the rest are [1] [2] [3] etc... so here is how i am doing it:

```
$news = new ManageNews();
$row = $news->getLatestNews('5');
  $article_id = $row['article_id'];
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $content = $row['content'];
  $date = $row['date'];
  print_r($row);
  $user = new ManageUsers();
  $row2 = $user->getUserById($user_id);
  if($row2 !== 1){
    $user_name = $row2['username'];
    $title2 = str_replace(" ","-",$title);
    echo '<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><h3 class="para"><a class="para" href="http://news.red-sec.net/article/'.$article_id.'/'.$title2.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>
    <p class="para">Written by: '.$user_name.'</p>
    </div>
    </div>';
  }
```

I am doing `print_r($row);` to see the array. when it works it just prints the newest one infinite times... i have no idea why it is doing that any help appreciated

this is what it looks like now:
http://prntscr.com/dz2b02

Comment: Because it executes the same query and returns the same first result every time you call `getLatestNews()`

Comment: i am passing in the limit through getLatestNews('5'); to get only 5 latest news

Comment: First thing that the function does is execute the query: `$query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit");`... it will repeat this every time the function is called.... and the function will then return the first row (if there are rows) or a 0.... it never tries to get the second or third or fourth, etc

Comment: th function is only called once and i know i did fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but when i do that i get an array with different arrays in it. i don't know how to access each one of these arrays the array looks like [ [ [news post 1] ] [ [news post 2 ] ] [ [news post 3] ] [] [] ]

Comment: is there a way to run a foreach on the array to get the seperate arrays in it ??

Comment: `while($row = $news->getLatestNews('5')){` is calling the function an infinite number of times, as long is it returns a result

Comment: i thought it worked like while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //do something }

Comment: It does.... and as `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` will always return the first row, it will forever iterate through the while time and again

Comment: how can i do it then ? mysqli_fetch_array used to return all rows for me

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` should ___never___ have returned all rows; that function has only ever returned a single row

Comment: with fetch all you will need a counter to access the extra rows, $i=0 before the while block and $i++ before its closing brace. Then use $row[$i] etc etc

Comment: Thanks but i fixed it using fetchAll and then i did a simple foreach($rows as $row) and did what i needed to do

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a Generator (just to keep the basic function similar to the way you've already written it)

```
function getLatestNews($limit){

    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit");
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    if ($count !== 0){

      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          yield $row;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ill try it and let u know

Comment: Generators cannot return values using "return" I get this error

Comment: function getLatestNews($limit){

        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit");
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        if ($count !== 0){

              while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              yield $row;

        }

        }else{

          return $count;

        }

    }

Comment: Where is there a return in the Generator code that I posted?

Comment: You'll get a `null` returned if there is no data to yield, or when the last record has been returned, which is a falsey result

Comment: can you please help ??

Comment: And what is it doing now?

Comment: i fixed it, i used a foreach($row as $r){//do what i was doing here} and i used fetchAll in the funciton getLatestNews

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by doing

```
while($row = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    return $row;
}
```

And in the file i did :

```
foreach($row as $r){do what i need to do}
```

Comment: Don't edit my answer if this is how i fixed it please... this fix works